# With drag and drop, is there a way to make a destination folder/app window stay on top with the source folder window underneath (Windows and Linux)?

Tags: linux, window, drag-and-drop, gestures, window-focus

Scenario:

You have a file Window, where you want to drag a file from, and on top of this Window is another window, the destination:  an app or other window.

So you click on the file you want on the window underneath, and what happens?  This is brought to the front (top) and so the destination window is out of view.  What a pain!

How can I make the destination window stay on top?

Windows and Linux, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, from the source window you can drag (click and hold the mouse button down) the file you're interesting in **first over the destination application (or folder) window in the taskbar *without* releasing it**, which will bring the window for the destination to the front, then continue and move the file into that window before finally releasing it.

That's not exactly what you asked for, but accomplishes the same thing, I believe. This will often also work if you first select two or more files before dragging and dropping (depending on the destination).

Answer (score 1):

In LINUX:

Hold **Alt** key while dragging and dropping a file from source to the destination folder or the app

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you click on the file and you don't let go (meaning that you do only click-down), then you drag the file and let-go (meaning click-up) on the target.

That way, the destination windows stays as the focus.